# javascript passing a function as an argument

Tags: javascript

I am wondering why when I make adjustments to the following code:

```
var product = {
firstname: "john",
lastname: "kcarl",
fullname : function() { return this.firstname + " " + this.lastname }
 };

function write()
{
document.write(product.fullname());

};
write();
```

**** the following  fullname becomes undefined

```
function write(method)
{
document.write(product.method());

};
write(fullname);
```

**** even when I try this it comes undefined

```
function write(method)
{
document.write(method());

};
write(product.fullname);
```

Comment: The first modification passes the `fullname` variable, which doesn't exist. The second passes the value of the `fullname` property, but separates it from the `product` object, so `this` won't reference `product`.

Comment: I don't suggest using `document.write()` at all

Comment: Just so you're not confused, `document.write()` has nothing to do with your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of scope issue with javascript. Here is a better way to write this code:

```
var Product = function() {
    var self = this;
    this.firstname = "john";
    this.lastname = "kcarl";
    this.fullname = function() {
        return self.firstname + " " + self.lastname;
    }
};

var product = new Product();
var fullnameMethod = product.fullname;
document.write(fullnameMethod());
```

In the above example, I save the scope into a variable called self and I can feel free to call the fullname() method anytime

Comment: user3369264 Please accept my answer if it solved your problem